# OpenWrt/network - Configuring dnsmasq for ad-blocking fails with "bad address at"

Tags: openwrt, adblock, dnsmasq

Trying to get ad blocking working in OpenWrt router firmware 10.03.1

I've prepared a file /etc/hosts.ads contain harmless entries like

```
address=/eviladserver1.com/127.0.0.1
address=/eviladserver2.com/127.0.0.1
```

in /etc/dnsmasq.conf I added the following line:

```
 addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.ads
```

and restarted dnsmasq.
Now on restart I see the log being filled with error messages:

```
Jun  3 22:52:33 OpenWrt daemon.err dnsmasq[13056]: bad address at /etc/hosts.ads line 1
```

about every single line in the hosts.ads
I googled it but with no luck. Everything seems right syntax-wise, why the dnsmasq does not like it?

(all lines in hosts.ads end with [LF] only)

Comment: Not a programming question, should be on superuser most likely.

Answer (score 2):

Appropriate format for /etc/hosts.ads is a standard HOSTS format such as:

```
127.0.0.1 eviladserver1.com
127.0.0.1 eviladserver2.com
```

Look at my implementation of adblock for OpenWRT at http://jazz.tvtom.pl/adblock-w-openwrt/ (polish).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [dnsmasq documentation](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html), `addn-hosts=` specifies additional addresses in `/etc/hosts` format. It looks like you're trying to add an additional dnsmasq configuration file instead. For that, you want `conf-file=` to specify the file directly, or you want to put the file in a directory specified by `conf-dir=`.